# Login validation & errors questions / concerns

Tags: php, forms, validation, twitter-bootstrap, authentication

Okay so basically I've always wanted to know how to develop a login form with instant validation & errors.. (Let me explain..)

Okay so basically i can easily construct a login form but I've never learned how to use form validation, nor errors..

So basically lets see i have a simple login form: http://blusttt.tk/login/

But as you can see from trying to login (just use any random combo) it leads to a new page with an ugly error message.. I want an error message to just appear (preferably by fading in & without the page reloading like professional sites have)

I'm down to learn anything.. Not looking for someone to do this for me (if you could that'd be great, but I learn very fast). Just cant find any good tutorials, and am very lost & i just overall really want to learn how to do this!

Thanks in advance, (that page utilizes bootstrap so I'f like to use alerts for the error & success messages that pop up)

Comment: *"I want an error message to just appear (preferably by fading in & without the page reloading..."* - You need a mix of JS/Ajax

Comment: Alright, thats a start! thanks @Fred-ii- .. Def puts me on the right track when googling examples / tutorials.. Do you have any resource that might help me?

Comment: jQuery has great documentation just look through that and AJAX

Comment: This should help a bit http://www.ondeweb.in/ajax-login-form-with-jquery-and-php/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using AJAX. Jquery provides a great wrapper around ajax. Your code would look something like this:

```
$("#loginbutton").click(function(){
  $.post("login.php",function(data,status){
    $('#errorMessageDiv').text(Data);
  });
});
```

here login.php would spit out the error message and the jQuery/AJAX code will grab the message and put it in a div on your page without any sort of redirection or something like that

Documentation on Jquery-Ajax:
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/